# div not taking full TailwindCSS row width and height

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Im trying to get my Card components to take the full width and height of my 4x4 Tailwindcss grid, right now they only take about 1/4 of the full width even with w-max.

Here's my code:

```
function Card({ title, description }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="border border-zinc-700 hover:bg-white-500 p rounded-md m-auto my-8">
      <div className="px-5 py-4">
        <h3 className="text-2xl mb-1 font-medium">ok</h3>
        <p className="text-zinc-300">{title}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="border-t border-zinc-700 bg-zinc-900 p-4 text-zinc-500 rounded-b-md">
        {description}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <section className="bg-black">
      <section className="bg-black">
        <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-8 sm:py-24 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:align-center">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-white sm:text-center sm:text-6xl">
              Nom
            </h1>
            <p className="mt-5 text-xl text-zinc-200 sm:text-center sm:text-2xl max-w-2xl m-auto">
              The Best Electronic Arbitrage Opportunity Finder.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section className="bg-zinc-900 flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1 w-4/5 place-items-center auto-cols-max auto-rows-max">
          <Card title="card-1" description="desc-1"></Card>
          <Card title="card-2" description="desc-2"></Card>
          <Card title="card-3" description="desc-3"></Card>
          <Card title="card-4" description="desc-4"></Card>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: please share your code from codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `w-full` to the card components main div, like:

```
 <div className="w-full border border-zinc-700 hover:bg-white-500 p rounded-md m-auto my-8">
      <div...>
```

See [this tailwind play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0bUc1PnSad) of your code.

The [`w-max` class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) will set the width to the maximum content width, `w-full` will use 100% of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

w-max is possible maximum value of your div.

it is created for more responsive behaviors.

w-full is '100% width'.
w-max is 'maximum width value that div.'

and if you want to know ;
h-full and h-max will give similar behaviors to your div for height.